# Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x0

Tags: anchor, rust, transaction-instructions

Getting this error and I know its regarding rent is less or something like that, but how to solve this? by adding more tokens to the program id??

```
const tx = await program
      .methods
      .vote(true)
      .accounts(
        {
          vote: ammAccount.publicKey
        }
      )
      .signers([ammAccount])
      .rpc()

    console.log(tx)

   const tx1 = await program
      .methods
      .vote(false)
      .accounts(
        {
          vote: ammAccount.publicKey
        }
      )
      .signers([ammAccount])
      .rpc()
```

These are 2 transactions I am executing one after another on devnet

Program - https://github.com/sk1122/anchor-dex-solana/blob/main/programs/dex/src/lib.rs

gm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PROBLEM SOLVED
The maximum space limit in Solana is 10,000 bytes. You use 10240.
I recommend that the account be PDA because it can be manipulated by you. (which is very insecure).
You only store 2 u64 variables (2*8 = 16 bytes). Don't confuse account space with native variable storage. Here I leave a guide for the solana space: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/space

Here is your code working.

Create in test folder a "Account.ts", then add :

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
anchor.setProvider(provider);
export const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

export const VoteAccount = new anchor.web3.PublicKey(
    "83xetaZnC4n37AxTwzUZXFnH8swQCyo9aQ8cypZh8bfA"
);
```

Create in test folder a "vote.ts", then add :

```
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Dex } from "../target/types/dex";
import { VoteAccount }  from "../tests/Account"

describe("Voting", () => {
    const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
    anchor.setProvider(provider);
    const program = anchor.workspace.Dex as Program<Dex>;
    const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

    it('Vote sent successfully', async () => {
        const tx = await program.methods.vote(true)
        .accounts({
            vote: VoteAccount,
            signer: wallet.publicKey,
        })
        .rpc()
        const Account = await program.account.voteAccount.fetch(VoteAccount);
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
        console.log("Tx: ",tx)
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
        console.log("Votes Yes: ", Account.yes.toString())
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
        console.log("Votes No: ", Account.no.toString())
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
        console.log("Bump seed: ", Account.bump.toString())
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
        console.log("Authority: ", Account.authority.toBase58())
        console.log("----------------------------------------")
      }
    )
  }
)
```

OnChain Code:

```
use anchor_lang::{
    prelude::*,
    solana_program::pubkey::Pubkey,
};
use std::str::FromStr;

declare_id!("7SCwRKLhG4b4NzqDkKscihYH6vFXpRm9dW3nkQrwaPck");

#[program]
pub mod dex {
    use super::*;

    pub fn create_vote(
        ctx: Context<Create>
    ) 
    -> Result<()> {
        let (_vote_account, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[ctx.accounts.signer.key().as_ref()], &Pubkey::from_str("7SCwRKLhG4b4NzqDkKscihYH6vFXpRm9dW3nkQrwaPck").unwrap());
        let vote = &mut ctx.accounts.vote;
        vote.authority = ctx.accounts.signer.key();
        vote.bump = bump;
        Ok(())
    }
    pub fn vote(
        ctx: Context<Vote>, 
        vote: bool
    ) -> Result<()> {
        let vote_account = &mut ctx.accounts.vote;
        if vote == true {
            vote_account.yes += 1;
        } else {
            vote_account.no += 1;
        }
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Create<'info> {
    #[account(init, seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()], bump, payer = signer, space = 8 + 8 + 8 + 32 + 1)]
    pub vote: Account<'info, VoteAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>
}
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Vote<'info> {
    #[account(mut, seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()], bump = vote.bump)]
    pub vote: Account<'info, VoteAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
}

#[account]
pub struct VoteAccount {
    pub authority: Pubkey, // You
    pub bump: u8,
    pub yes: u64, // from 0 to 9223372036854775807
    pub no: u64 // from 0 to 9223372036854775807
}

#[error_code]
pub enum ErrCode {
    #[msg("Authority Key not equal to Swap Authority Key")]
    AuthorityKeyNotEqualToSwapAuthorityKey
}
```

dex.ts:

```
import { Dex } from "../target/types/dex";
import * as anchor from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { Program } from "@project-serum/anchor";
import { PublicKey, Connection } from '@solana/web3.js'
const { SystemProgram } = anchor.web3;

describe("dex", () => {
  const provider = anchor.AnchorProvider.env();
  anchor.setProvider(provider);
  const program = anchor.workspace.Dex as Program<Dex>;
  const wallet = provider.wallet as anchor.Wallet;

  it("Is initialized!", async () => {
    const sig = await provider.connection.requestAirdrop(
      wallet.publicKey,
      10000000
    )
    const [VoteAccount, _bump] = await PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [
        wallet.publicKey.toBuffer()
      ],
      program.programId
    )
    const tx = await program.methods.createVote()
      .accounts({
        vote: VoteAccount,
        signer: wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId
      }).rpc()
      console.log("----------------------------------------")
      console.log("Tx: ", tx)
      console.log("----------------------------------------")
      console.log("Vote Account:", VoteAccount.toBase58());
      console.log("----------------------------------------")
    
  });
});
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "dex"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Created with Anchor"
edition = "2021"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
name = "dex"

[features]
no-entrypoint = []
no-idl = []
no-log-ix-name = []
cpi = ["no-entrypoint"]
default = []

[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.25.0"
```

Anchor.toml:

```
[features]
seeds = false
skip-lint = false

[programs.localnet]
dex = "BBf9Y9MctDrsip8ejGpfJhSXGacaYQEscesvAMVzKSsR"

[programs.devnet]
dex = "7SCwRKLhG4b4NzqDkKscihYH6vFXpRm9dW3nkQrwaPck"

[registry]
url = "https://api.apr.dev"

[provider]
cluster = "devnet"
wallet = "/home/mateo/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
create = "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/dex.ts"
vote =  "yarn run ts-mocha -p ./tsconfig.json -t 1000000 tests/vote.ts"
```

Run `anchor run create`
Then you take the publickey that appears in the terminal and paste it into account.ts. Then run `anchor run vote`

My GitHub: https://github.com/mateolafalce

Comment: Thanks for the help Mateo, so by using PDA, i am first initializing the account which I can then further use?

but not understanding one thing, I am manually send vote account address, so it will know which account I am editing from, so it should update that account instead of reinitiating a new account? or it doesn't work that way

Comment: Of course!, the from account is variable, so any account can vote.

Answer (score 0):

`0x0` means that you're attempting to initialize an already initialized account. If `tx` initializes your vote account then `tx1` fails because it tries to initialize it again.